# Problems with spec that works with Time

Tags: ruby, time, rspec2

In my spec I need to verify whether strings are being converted correctly to other types. Among these are `Time`, `Date` and `DateTime`.

The tests work fine with all types including `Date`, but it fails when `Time` is involved:

```
let(:type) { DateTime }
let(:date_time) { type.now }
let(:params) { [ date_time.to_s ] }

it 'should convert the parameters to dates/times' do
  # converted basically calls params.map { |param| type.parse param }
  converted.should == [date_time]
end
```

This actually *almost* works:

```
expected: [#<DateTime: 2012-01-17T15:03:27-02:00 ((2455944j,61407s,568873440n),-7200s,2299161j)>]
     got: [#<DateTime: 2012-01-17T15:03:27-02:00 ((2455944j,61407s,0n),-7200s,2299161j)>] (using ==)
```

The diff is off by only one value, but I don't know what exactly it means. The result of the `Time` test is even more confusing:

```
expected: [2012-01-17 15:03:27 -0200]
     got: [2012-01-17 15:03:27 -0200] (using ==)
```

The only differences between the tests are the type and the description. After some tracing, it appears to me that the parsed times have no microsecond precision; `usec` always returns 0.

Any tips on how to make these specs pass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try comparing their string representations using a [formatting which excludes the fields that you do not want to compare](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-iso8601) (e.g. millis, micros, etc).

```
converted[0].iso8601(0).should == date_time.iso8601(0)
```

**[Edit]** Note that the above example compares the two DateTimes without any fractional seconds (see the linked `iso8601` docs above).

If you really want to compare the DateTime objects themselves then your test code is complete, you'll just have to fix your implementation to adjust the fractional seconds part to some fixed value (e.g. zero).

Comment: Your solution works, but I'd like to compare the `DateTime`s themselves if possible. The `to_s` method returns an ISO 8601 string, and the documentation states it doesn't use the expanded representations. Is there a format which returns a string with full precision? If there isn't, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Changed implementation to use a less precise version of the current time:

```
  let(:type) { DateTime }
- let(:date_time) { type.now }
+ let(:date_time) { type.parse type.now.to_s }
```